# Run node js from php shell_exec()

Tags: php, node.js, exec, system-calls

Hi I uploded some files to parse which parsed by `node js`. currently I am running it from terminal as `node app.js`.

I need to call it from my php model.

I am thinking `shell_exec()` function will help. I tried like this

```
shell_exec('http://172.18.18.219/hrms_work/web/uplodedfiles/test/code4goal-resume-parser/app.js');
```

but it dose not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. your `shell_exec()` argument is wrong. Does this argument work in your terminal? Probably not because is a simple link.
2. Does your file `app.js` have the correct permissions to run Apache user?

After answering these questions, make sure you enter the correct argument in `shell_exec()`: absolute path to `app.js` and the same command you use in terminal I think is `node app.js`.

something like
`shell_exec(node /absolute/path/to/app.js);`

please let us know ;)

Answer (score 4):

You're not executing any command, that's why it doesn't work. `shell_exec()` take exactly what you'd write in a terminal so this should work better `shell_exec('node app.js')`. But you will also have to `cd` to the right directory or provide an absolute path to `app.js`. You're using an url to `app.js`, I'm not sure `node` can run a remote file like that.